# Debian install: GNOME not booting and unknown Wifi drivers

Tags: debian, networking, gnome

I'm installing Debian on my new laptop from a USB stick with the DVD1 image. I can install it successfully if I skip the network driver selection part.

However it doesn't boot up to the GUI: `systemctl` tells me that `gdm3` (GNOME) is active, but it shows a blinking underscore forever. So my first question is, **why doesn't GNOME show up?**

As for then enabling the network, I'm missing many packages to follow advice from some other SE answers. Perhaps the driver is actually on the DVD, but I have no clue how to find the one that the laptop needs. Regarding the network hardware, the only information I can gather is as follows:

```bsh
~$ lspci -n -s 01:00.0
01:00.0 0280: 10ec:c822
~$ lspci -vv -s 01:00.0
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device c822
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 85f7
        Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 255
        Region 0: I/O ports at 2000 [disabled] [size=256]
        Region 2: Memory at d0800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=64K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
```

Nothing seem to fit these information in the list of drivers from the debian installer from DVD1. **How do I find which network driver I need? Can I install it from a USB stick after installing the OS?**

Comment: `lshw -numeric -C network` ?  Also, is your kernel by any chance older than 5.2?  `uname -a`

Comment: @Pourko Kernel is 4.19. `lshw` is unknown.

Comment: Can't remember where, but I think I saw somewhere that this card works well with kernels 5.2 and up. I could be wrong though. Google it.

Comment: @Pourko I just installed the latest image for Debian with kernel 5-9-0. Gnome launches! I tried all the pilots but none fit. Where can I find the pilot for this hardware? Does it exist? How do I install it?